# Intel Core i7-1065g7 Windows 10 node 6.9.2 correctly not working?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use node 6.9.2 and install some packages. But it gives following SSL error.

```
101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2010
```

Comment: Hi Chathura,
Did you ever resolve this issue?  I now have exactly the same problem!
Thanks.
Paul